# Get data from three tables in a single query

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have three tables like this.

**userLogin**

```
  userID   userPassword
  c01      chutop
  c02      213jkd
```

**SystemUser**

```
userID      FName     LName    CategoryID
c01         Sidy      Kamal    2 
c02         Bindu     Namal    1
c03         Sandy     Khan     3
```

**SystemUserCategory**

```
CatID  CatType
1      Admin
2      General
3      Librarian
```

When I enter `userID='c01'` and `userPassword` as `chutop` in the query, what I want to get in the results set is:

```
userID     FName    LName    catType
c01        Sidy     Kamal    Genaral
```

I'm entering user name and the password. I want to get the `Fname`, `LName` and `catType` for the matching record.  Further more, I'm going to login as `userID c01`, entering `userID c01` and the password as `chutop`. I want to retrieve the `Fname` and `Lname` from the `User` Table for `userID='c01'` and I want to get the `catType` from the `Category` table for the `userID='c01'`s `catID`, which is 2 in this case.

Here's what I tried.

```
SELECT userFName, userLName, catID 
FROM userLogin, SystemUser, SystemUserCategory 
WHERE  userLogin.userID='c001' AND userLogin.userPassword='chath';
```

It gives me 12 records instead of 1 record.

Any help in correcting this or any query help would be really great.

Comment: google `sql join tutorial`

Comment: Are you really storing passwords as plain text?

Comment: You need to specify how the tables are related to each other. Look at this: http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/The_JOIN_operation

Comment: @jpw Your tutorial was very helpful. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my answer.

```
SELECT userFName,UserLName,CatName
FROM userLogin INNER JOIN SystemUser ON (userLogin.userID=SystemUSer.userID) INNER JOIN SystemUserCategory ON (SystemUser.userCatID=SystemUserCategory.catID)
WHERE UserLogin.userID='c002' AND UserLogin.userPassword='ryan';
```

Apply the necessary username and password. The userid and the password are just what I added.

Answer (score 0):

You must use inner join instead of selecting from multiple tables.

Like this:

```
select userFName, userLName,catID 
from userLogin UL inner join SystemUser SU 
 on Ul.userId = SU.userId inner join SystemUserCategory SUC 
 on SU.CatID = SUC.CatID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select ul.UserId,su.FName,su.LName,suc.CatType 
from UserLogin ul
inner join SystemUser su on ul.UserId = su.UserId
inner join SystemUserCategory suc on su.CategoryId = suc.CatId
where ul.userId = 'c01' and ul.[Password] = 'chutop'
```

[image]

Answer (score -2):

SELECT userFName, userLName, catID
    FROM    userLogin, SystemUser, SystemUserCategory
    WHERE    userLogin.userID='c001'
        AND    userLogin.userPassword='chath'
        AND    SystemUser.userID = userLogin.userID
        AND    SystemUser.CategoryID = SystemUserCategory.CategoryID